MetaQuest3にMicrosoft Kinect　V2のデータを送りたいです。
現在私はMicrosoftKinectのデータを送信してUnitychanをトラッキングしたいのですが、MetaQuest3でKinectのデータをうまく受信することができません。どなたかKinectのデータをMetaQuest3で受信してトラッキングする方法を知りませんか？ちなみに現在使用している送信方法はUDP通信です。そして、現状としては、MetaQuest3でBuild and Runを実行して、Kinectがトラッキングに成功していても棒立ち状態になっています。
こちらが送信側のスクリプトです。
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;
using UnityEngine;
using Windows.Kinect;

public class KinectDataSender : MonoBehaviour
{
    private UdpClient udpClient; // UDP通信のクライアント
    private int port = 12345; // 送信先ポート番号
    private string ipAddress = "IPアドレス"; // 
    private BodySourceManager bodySourceManager;

    void Start()
    {
        udpClient = new UdpClient(); // UdpClientの初期化
        bodySourceManager = FindObjectOfType<BodySourceManager>(); // BodySourceManagerを取得
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (bodySourceManager == null) return;

        // ボディデータを取得
        var data = bodySourceManager.GetData();
        if (data == null) return;

        // トラッキングされているボディを取得
        var body = data.FirstOrDefault(b => b.IsTracked);
        if (body != null)
        {
            SendJointData(body); // 関節データを送信
        }
    }

    private void SendJointData(Body body)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (JointType jointType in (JointType[])Enum.GetValues(typeof(JointType)))
        {
            var joint = body.Joints[jointType];
            sb.Append($"{jointType}:{joint.Position.X},{joint.Position.Y},{joint.Position.Z};");
        }

        string message = sb.ToString();
        byte[] dataToSend = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message); // メッセージをバイト配列に変換
        udpClient.Send(dataToSend, dataToSend.Length, ipAddress, port); // UDPでデータを送信
        Debug.Log($"Sent: {message}"); // 送信したメッセージをログに表示
        
    }

    void OnApplicationQuit()
    {
        udpClient.Close(); // アプリケーション終了時にUDPクライアントを閉じる
    }

    
}

そしてこちらが受信側のスクリプトです。
using UnityEngine;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;
using System;

public class KinectDataReceiver : MonoBehaviour
{
    private UdpClient udpClient; // UDP通信のクライアント
    private int port = 12345; // 受信するポート番号

    // UnityChanの各関節を格納するための変数
    public Transform Hips;
    public Transform Spine1;
    public Transform Spine2;
    public Transform LeftShoulder;
    public Transform RightShoulder;
    public Transform LeftArm;
    public Transform RightArm;
    public Transform LeftForeArm;
    public Transform RightForeArm;
    public Transform LeftHand;
    public Transform RightHand;
    public Transform Neck;
    public Transform Head;
    public Transform LeftUpLeg;
    public Transform RightUpLeg;
    public Transform LeftLeg;
    public Transform RightLeg;

    void Start()
    {
        // UDPクライアントの初期化
        udpClient = new UdpClient(port);
        udpClient.BeginReceive(new AsyncCallback(ReceiveData), null);
        Debug.Log("UDP Receiver started on port " + port);
    }

    private void ReceiveData(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        try
        {
            IPEndPoint remoteEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, port);
            byte[] data = udpClient.EndReceive(ar, ref remoteEndPoint); // データを受信

            string message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data); // バイト配列を文字列に変換
            //Debug.Log($"Received Data: {message}"); // 受信したメッセージを表示
            UpdateUnityChanPosition(message); // UnityChanの位置を更新
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.LogError($"Error receiving data: {ex.Message}"); // エラーログを表示
        }
        finally
        {
            // 再び受信を開始
            udpClient.BeginReceive(new AsyncCallback(ReceiveData), null);
        }
    }

    private void UpdateUnityChanPosition(string message)
    {
        // メッセージを解析して関節データを取得
        string[] jointData = message.Split(';');
        foreach (string joint in jointData)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(joint)) continue;

            string[] parts = joint.Split(':');
            if (parts.Length != 2) continue;

            string jointType = parts[0];
            string[] position = parts[1].Split(',');

            // UnityChanの関節位置を更新
            if (position.Length == 3)
            {
                Vector3 jointPosition;
                if (float.TryParse(position[0], out float x) &&
                    float.TryParse(position[1], out float y) &&
                    float.TryParse(position[2], out float z))
                {
                    jointPosition = new Vector3(x, y, z); // パースに成功した場合のみ位置を更新
                }
                else
                {
                    Debug.LogWarning($"Failed to parse position for {jointType}: {string.Join(",", position)}"); // パース失敗のログ
                    continue;
                }

                // UnityChanの関節に応じて位置を更新
                switch (jointType)
                {
                    case "SpineBase":
                        Hips.position = jointPosition; // Hipsの位置を更新
                        break;
                    case "SpineMid":
                        Spine1.position = jointPosition; // Spine1の位置を更新
                        break;
                    case "SpineShoulder":
                        Spine2.position = jointPosition; // Spine2の位置を更新
                        break;
                    case "ShoulderLeft":
                        LeftShoulder.position = jointPosition; // 左肩の位置を更新
                        break;
                    case "ShoulderRight":
                        RightShoulder.position = jointPosition; // 右肩の位置を更新
                        break;
                    case "ElbowLeft":
                        LeftArm.position = jointPosition; // 左肘の位置を更新
                        break;
                    case "ElbowRight":
                        RightArm.position = jointPosition; // 右肘の位置を更新
                        break;
                    case "WristLeft":
                        LeftForeArm.position = jointPosition; // 左手首の位置を更新
                        break;
                    case "WristRight":
                        RightForeArm.position = jointPosition; // 右手首の位置を更新
                        break;
                    case "HandLeft":
                        LeftHand.position = jointPosition; // 左手の位置を更新
                        break;
                    case "HandRight":
                        RightHand.position = jointPosition; // 右手の位置を更新
                        break;
                    case "Neck":
                        Neck.position = jointPosition; // 首の位置を更新
                        break;
                    case "Head":
                        Head.position = jointPosition; // 頭の位置を更新
                        break;
                    case "HipLeft":
                        LeftUpLeg.position = jointPosition; // 左腰の位置を更新
                        break;
                    case "HipRight":
                        RightUpLeg.position = jointPosition; // 右腰の位置を更新
                        break;
                    case "KneeLeft":
                        LeftLeg.position = jointPosition; // 左膝の位置を更新
                        break;
                    case "KneeRight":
                        RightLeg.position = jointPosition; // 右膝の位置を更新
                        break;
                    case "AnkleLeft":
                        LeftLeg.position = jointPosition; // 左足首の位置を更新
                        break;
                    case "AnkleRight":
                        RightLeg.position = jointPosition; // 右足首の位置を更新
                        break;
                    case "FootLeft":
                        LeftLeg.position = jointPosition; // 左足の位置を更新
                        break;
                    case "FootRight":
                        RightLeg.position = jointPosition; // 右足の位置を更新
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    void OnApplicationQuit()
    {
        udpClient.Close(); // アプリケーション終了時にUDPクライアントを閉じる
    }
}

